# The date formats do not seem to work in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am wanting to create a report which contains a table with dates.

The format property for the AnnualLeaveDate textbox I am using is;

=FORMAT(Fields!AnnualLeaveDate.Value, "ddd d MMMM yyyy")

So I want a date like Mon 4 August 2011

### What I am getting is this;

Annual Leave Date

Tue 15 Nove0ber 2011

We16 16 Nove0ber 2011

T12u 17 Nove0ber 2011

ri 18 Nove0ber 2011

11on 21 Nove0ber 2011

---

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?
I am using SSRS 2008.

Comment: The expression format string 'ddd d MMMM yyyy' is working as expected in my testing. Can you confirm that the AnnualLeaveDate is an actual datetime value?

Comment: In the dataset the field is defined as follows;<Field Name="AnnualLeaveDate">
          <DataField>AnnualLeaveDate</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the problem in report builder...double-check the expression syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the date field in a "Cdate" function as in:

```
=FORMAT(Cdate(Fields!AnnualLeaveDate.Value), "ddd d MMMM yyyy")
```

or

wrap the date field in the Cdate function (assignment expression) and then use the date formmating on the dialog display like you would any other data field.

```
=Cdate(Fields!AnnualLeaveDate.Value)
```

Comment: Am having exact same problem. CDate wrapper isn't helping. Any other solution?