# Weird SSRS Format Date Output in Header

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

For one of my Matrix reports, the column headers are Dates which I am trying to format in the form of 'Mon 07' i.e. short date name followed by date value.

For this I am using the expression - =Format(CDate(Fields!WorkedOnDate.Value),"ddd") 
I then wanted to trim the right 3 letters.

I am getting weird output.
Here is what I am getting for one week-
Tue, We2, T12u,ri,SaA,Sun,7on

Any idea what is going wrong?
This was asked in this link but that answer didn't help - 
[The date formats do not seem to work in SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8402506/the-date-formats-do-not-seem-to-work-in-ssrs/14884619#comment38294400_14884619)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize my mistake now. I was adding the Format property across Number-> Format property of that textbox. I solved this by adding as part of the textbox Property value.